# Twitter Crawler for Trends

Tags: twitter, web-crawler

I would like to track the trending topics on twitter over a period of time, I am assuming from my knowledge the best way to do this would be through a crawler, does anyone know of any existing code available or can make some recommendations as to how best to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start here

http://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place